# Copying All Files Without A Particular String Glob Negation

Tags: bash, glob

I have several files in a directory, but some files include the text `Copy` within their names. For example, `fileCopy.txt`. I want to move all the files that don't contain the string `Copy` in their names to the higher directory, but neither of the statements I've tried work.

```
mv *!(Copy)* ..
mv !(Copy) ..
```

All these statements have given me the same result. They copy everything from the directory, including the files that feature `Copy` in their title. It would also be nice to not have to go back and move the directory `directory` back into the original folder, but none of the statements I've tried work.

```
mv !((*Copy*)|(directory)) ..
mv (*!(Copy)*|!(directory)) ..
mv !(Copy|directory) ..
```

The first one had a syntax error. The second one moved everything from the current directory to the higher directory. The third one moved everything from the current directory to the higher directory, except `directory`.

Answer (score 2):

Make this statement to prevent all the files that contain the text `Copy` within their names from being moved.

```
mv !(*Copy*) ..
```

To prevent all the files that contain the text `Copy` within their names and `directory` from being moved, make this statement.

```
mv !(*Copy*|directory) ..
```